# SVG Bitmap Code for Number to real Number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

This working codepen demo [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/xxJaGjE?editors=1000) shows SVG code that makes up the **Number 9 in terms of bitmaps**. May I ask if there is a way to **convert the bitmaps into a real number 9 that is readable**? The Number 9 color is a little faint in my demo, so have to look closely.

Any help will be very much appreciated :)

SVG Code for Number 9

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 0 1066.6667 800"
   height="800"
   width="1066.6667"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"><metadata
     id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs6" /><g
     transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,800)"
     id="g10"><path
       id="path20"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.074;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 294.09,426.05 -0.46,-1.38 -0.92,-0.92 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.46 l -1.37,0.46 -0.92,0.92 -0.46,1.38 v 0.46 l 0.46,1.37 0.92,0.92 1.37,0.46 h 0.46 l 1.38,-0.46 0.92,-0.92 0.46,-1.83 v -2.3 l -0.46,-2.29 -0.92,-1.38 -1.38,-0.46 h -0.91 l -1.38,0.46 -0.46,0.92" /></g></svg>
```

Comment: Of course, there are services that recognize pictures very well and translate them into text, and they offer programmers to use the API to recognize pictures.

Comment: It's a vector `<path>` element and not a bitmap. Not sure if tesseract can candle vector shapes - I'm afraid you need to convert the svg to a bitmap first and run tesseracts OCR afterwards.